# String iteration, value check logic

Tags: python, string, loops, conditional-statements

I’m new to coding and python in general and I’m taking a course to start to expand my resume of sorts.
I’m at the stage where we are just getting into loops and conditionals.

The prompt is to write a program that can validate or invalidate a text string based on certain conditions of the string.

The conditions are as follows:

1. “All strings must start with at least two letters.”
2. “… strings may contain a maximum of 6 characters (letters or numbers) and a minimum of 2 characters.”
3. “Numbers cannot be used in the middle of strings they must come at the end. For example, AAA222 would be an acceptable string; AAA22A would not be acceptable. The first number used cannot be a ‘0’.”
4. “No periods, spaces, or punctuation marks are allowed.”

the bones for this problem is:

```
def main():
plate = input("string: ")
if is_valid(string):
    print("Valid")
else:
    print("Invalid")
def is_valid(s):
...
main()
```

the problem I'm having is that I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding the question or I'm overcomplicating it. conditions 1,2 and 4 seem easy enough, it is mainly condition 3 I'm really struggling with

how to write the code to parse if the numbers are only in the latter half of the string and if the number part starts with a 0. using essentially only intro-level Python code. I could be missing something very obvious.

I am just sort of brute forcing I wrote a function to see if I could see any avenues or ways through, yet I'm stuck, I'm just trying to write a function to evaluate condition 3 and return true or false.

```
def is_num(string):
i=0
while i < (len(string)):
    for c in string:
        #print(c, end="")
        if c.isalpha() == False:
            if c == "0":
                return False
            else:
                i+=1
        else:
            i+=1
```

but then again, I'm very new and very lost.

Comment: There are quite a few other questions with the exact same prompt, since it's a CS50 problem set.

Comment: One approach would be to split the string into two parts: a mandatory initial alphabetic part, and an optional part that contains everything from the first digit to the end of the string.  If the second part starts with 0 or contains any letters, it's invalid.